# remove html element from shinymanager

Tags: html, r, shiny

Hello.

I would like to remove the "Please authenticate" text element from shinymanager.

 I have tried shinyjs `html()` function but I can't get it to work with elements from shinymanager.
[image]

Sample Code:

```
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"),
  password = c("azerty", "12345"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

ui <- secure_app(fluidPage())

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
As akron pointed out, I can remove the text with the `set_labels()` function in `secure_app()`. However, if you want to remove the leftover space you would have to add this argument as well:

```
secure_app(ui,head_auth=tags$style(".h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3 {margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;}"),
set_labels(language="en","Please authenticate"=""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `set_labels`

```
set_labels(
  language = "en",
  "Please authenticate" = "")
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks akrun. This does remove the text, but the element still seems to be there. The issue is the empty space above the username input. Any solution to making that shorter?

Comment: @niceguy sorry, i am not sure about it.

Comment: It's alright I figured it out, going to edit the solution to the original post. Thanks again.

Comment: @niceguy I was trying with `tags$style(`

Comment: @niceguy I missed the `head_auth` part.  Nice option in your update